# Evaluating a definite integral of the product of a power function and an arbitrary density function

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, definite-integrals

I cannot seem to get any traction on evaluating an integral of this form:
$$\int_{0}^1f(x)x^ydx,$$
where $f(x)$ is some arbitrary density function.

Is there an analytic solution to this form? Are there any existing solutions or concepts in probability or calculus that might be of use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y$ is an integer and $f$ is supported on $[0, 1]$, then this expression is the $y$th [moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)) of $f$, which is $E_{x \sim f}[x^y]$. If $f$ is a well-known distribution, you might be able to look up this integral as a property of the distribution. Otherwise, you could get some traction by looking into the distribution's [moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function), which is a polynomial whose Taylor expansion is related to these integrals.